# Good practice with MIMO/antennas (Wi-Fi or LTE)

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a wireless card with 2 connectors. I can plug several kinds of compatible antennas, with different shapes, gains and orientations.

Is it better to…

1. Use same antennas, aligned, to have the same gain & spectrum (better for MIMO)?
2. Use different antennas (bad for MIMO I guess, but better for global coverage)?

Is it the same answer for Wi-Fi (2.4GHz) and LTE devices?

My LTE card is a Mikrotik R11e-LTE (connectors labelled Main/Aux)

My Wi-Fi card is a Mikrotik R11e-2hpnd (connectors labelled 0/1)

Comment: Labeling the connectors "main" and "aux" suggests SISO with diversity, not MIMO. MIMO would be more likely to label them "0" and "1", or "1" and "2". What is the make and model of your wireless card (or the chipset on your wireless card)? It sounds like you have a 1x1 card with antenna diversity, so most of your question may not actually apply to your situation.

Comment: Question edited.. i have both models :)